# How can I retrieve data using PyMongo?

Tags: python, pymongo, pymodm

I have read the tutorials and because I am using three seperate things:
1. Flask as a server
2. PyMongo as a MongoDB driver
3. PyMODM as a schema creator

I got confused already.

First, I have defined the Schema using PyMODM:

```
from pymongo import TEXT
from pymongo.operations import IndexModel
from pymodm import connect, fields, MongoModel, EmbeddedMongoModel

class GoalPosition(EmbeddedMongoModel):
    x = fields.IntegerField()
    y = fields.IntegerField()

class GoalOrientation(EmbeddedMongoModel):
    x = fields.IntegerField()

class Goal(EmbeddedMongoModel):
    position = fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(GoalPosition)
    orientation = fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(GoalOrientation)

class Path(MongoModel):
    path = fields.EmbeddedDocumentListField(Goal)
```

From the above, my idea is to make two types of schemas: Goal and Path. At the end, Goal would look like this:

```
{
    "position": {
        "x": "1",
        "y": "6"
    },
    "orientation": {
        "x": "0"
    }
}
```

And Path will be a list of Goals.
Having my schema, the big question is, how can I use that to communicate with my MongoDB database? Here is my small server code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, request, logging
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask import jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb+srv://user:pass@cluster0-qhfvu.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true"
mongo = PyMongo(app)

@app.route('/goal', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def goals():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        goals = mongo.db.goals.find()
        return jsonify(goals)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        position = request.body.position
        orientation = request.body.orientation
        print position
        flash("Goal added")

@app.route('/goal/<id>')
def goal(id):
    goal = mongo.db.goals.find_one_or_404({"_id" : id})
    return jsonify(goal)
```

So by focusing only on GET method at route '/goal', **how can I retrieve all the Goal messages from my database?**

Also, I want to know **how can I retrieve a last Goal message at '/goal/' ?**

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're already doing that. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Are you saying that my code is correct? But how can flask server and pymongo know what "mongo.db.goals.find()"  is?

Answer (score 1):

```
def goals():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        goals = mongo.db.goals.find()
        return jsonify(goals)
```

You are already retrieving all the records in goals collection. Below example will give you single most updated record.

```
def goals():
        if request.method == 'GET':
        goals = mongo.db.goals.find().sort({'_id',-1}).limit(1)
        return jsonify(goals)
```

.

```
def goals():
        if request.method == 'GET':
        goals = mongo.db.goals.find().sort({'_id',-1})
        return jsonify(goals)
```

Above example will return list of all data in goals collection in descending order means last updates will be on top

To Find

```
mongo.db.goals.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})
```